# Python eval function and instance methods

Tags: python, python-2.7

How Do i evaluate string representation name of string class instance methods through python `eval` method
as example

`f=eval(raw_input())`

input:
upper

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'upper' is not defined`

Comment: `f=eval(raw_input())`? See http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Comment: @ JohnColeman Thanks

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do, but: `'upper' in dir(str)` evaluates to `True`. You can use `dir` to look up class methods

Comment: Can you give us more details on what you want to do? In your example, you used `eval` to compile and run a python expression that simply references a name called `upper`. That name does not exist in the current global/local scope. You could do `f=eval('str.' + raw_input())` and then `f` would be `<method 'upper' of 'str' objects>`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Why not `getattr(str, 'upper')`?

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What will solving this problem allow you to accomplish?  What is the bigger problem you are solving?